# All $2$-designs arising from the action of the affine linear group on the field of prime order

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, combinatorial-designs

Let $p$ be a prime and $\mathbb{Z}_p$ denote as usual the field of order $p$. Let $AL(p)$ be the affine linear group $\{x\mapsto ax+b \;|\; a\in \mathbb{Z}_p\setminus \{0\}, b\in\mathbb{Z}_p\}$. For a given integer $1\leq k \leq p$, it is known that each orbit of the natural action of $AL(p)$ on $k$-subsets of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a $2$-design $D_k(p)$.

Are all such $2$-designs $D_k(p)$ known?

Any information on a generic $D_k(p)$ for an arbitrary $p$ and $k$ is apreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For fixed $k \ge 3$, the generic such design is a full orbit with "index" $\lambda = k(k-1)$ and is probably not of much (combinatorial) interest.  Short orbits are, of course, very interesting.  As an example, developing $\{1,2,4\}$ under the field of order $7$ gives the Fano plane.  Replace $7$ by a larger prime and this is just a rather boring (setting aside intricate structural questions) design with index six.

I believe most researchers in combinatorics and group theory "know" about these designs.  But if by "known" you are asking about the question of classification, then [difference sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_set) and their multipliers can yield challenging sub-problems.

Comment: As far as I know for the orbit of a $k$-subset $S$ of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, $\lambda=\frac{k(k-1)}{|Stab_{AL(p)}(S)|}$, where $Stab_{AL(p)}(S)=\{\alpha\in AL(p) \;|\; S^\alpha=S\}$. So you are claiming that $|Stab_{AL(p)}(S)|=1$. Could you please give a hint for this?

Comment: I just meant that in most cases the stabilizer is trivial.  That is what I thought you meant by "generic".

Comment: so I would like to know how you arrived to the point that in the generic case The stabilizer is trivial?